# Custom Expandable list

Tags: android, expandablelistview

How to customized expandable list in android, i have to design, a imageview, textview and imageButton in child's view in same row. and click event on that imageButton. how to achieve it, Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
    LinearLayout rowView;
    Color color = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null)
    {
      rowView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
      LayoutInflater vi =
          (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      vi.inflate(textViewResourceId, rowView, true);
    }
    else
    {
      rowView = (LinearLayout) convertView;
    }

    TextView name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.color_name_txt);
    CheckBox colorCheckbox = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.color_checkbox);

    meaning.setText(color.getName());
    colorCheckbox.setChecked(color.isChecked());

    return rowView;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check the example [here](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2010/02/expandable-lists-and-check-boxes.html) Hope this may help u..

Google's API Demos [Expandable ListView](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html)